# how to implement a cards layout that displays a user's string input from an EditText view?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-keep

I am developing a workout app, but I am stuck because I don't know how to save a user's input and then display that information on cards layout in the main activity. I am going for a layout that is very similar to Google's Google Keep.

Comment: Please post some code you already have so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Well so as to get the EditText string you can always do `editText.getText()`. I recommend you put a button somewhere and put the `getText` method insde the button's `onClick`.

One thing you can do to display it is to use a `VerticalLayout` as your base activity Layout and then add `HorizontalLayout` which will be kind of rows and each card can be a `VerticalLayout`. You can always save this `VerticalLayout` in your `resources/layouts` folder like `card.xml` and then make a method that inflates this layout and put the information on it. The thing is they will have the same height and maybe you don't want that, but I can't think of anything else right now.

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want the user to create multiple cards, how would I save the string that the input and then call it back again?

Comment: you can do something like `ArrayList<String> values` and put them all inside of it and then just call them using a `for (String card : values)`

Comment: If you want to save them inside the device I recommend you use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). It would be better if you could save them inside a cloud database and do something so people can log in and get their cards no matter what device they're using. [Parse](https://www.parse.com) is a very nice and easy way of doing it!

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into those and update you. Thanks again